# WPF: can't bind object to listbox

Tags: wpf, object, listbox, bind

Trying to bind a `listbox` to an object. Code runs without errors but for some reason sample data doesn't appear in `listbox`

XAML: `ucDataBindingObject.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="TheProject.UserControls.ucDataBindingObject"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             Name="DataBindingObject"
             Width="Auto"
             Height="Auto"
             mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Width="130"
          Height="240"
          Margin="0">

        <ListBox Name="lbObject"
                 Width="110"
                 Height="80"
                 Margin="10,7,-9.6,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ucDataBindingObject,
                                       Path=Clients}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C#: `ucDataBindingObject.xaml.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace TheProject.UserControls
{
    public partial class ucDataBindingObject : UserControl
    {

        public List<Client> Clients { get; set; }


        public ucDataBindingObject()
        {
            Clients = new List<Client>();
            Clients.Add(new Client(1, "David")); // sample data
            Clients.Add(new Client(2, "Helen"));
            Clients.Add(new Client(3, "Joe"));


            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

C# `Client.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace TheProject.UserControls
{
    public class Client
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Client(int id, string name)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your ItemsSource Binding as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Clients}"
```

and in the constructor of your view, set its DataContext after InitializeComponents as

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

there is no element named ucDataBindingObject, its the class name of your usercontrol

OR change the elementname in binding to DataBindingObject, which you named your usercontrol

Comment: Ah.Thought I had to reference the code behind file. Worked like a charm. Thanks for help.